# Python: Where is documented which exceptions might be raised by socket functions?

Tags: python, sockets

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html) of the selectors module comes with an example program for a multiplexed echo server.

```py
import selectors
import socket

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

def accept(sock, mask):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()  # Should be ready
    print('accepted', conn, 'from', addr)
    conn.setblocking(False)
    sel.register(conn, selectors.EVENT_READ, read)

def read(conn, mask):
    data = conn.recv(1000)  # Should be ready
    if data:
        print('echoing', repr(data), 'to', conn)
        conn.send(data)  # Hope it won't block
    else:
        print('closing', conn)
        sel.unregister(conn)
        conn.close()

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('localhost', 1234))
sock.listen(100)
sock.setblocking(False)
sel.register(sock, selectors.EVENT_READ, accept)

while True:
    events = sel.select()
    for key, mask in events:
        callback = key.data
        callback(key.fileobj, mask)
```

The program has a noteworthy comment in it:

```py
conn.send(data)  # Hope it won't block
```

In fact, it is rather easy to provoke the program to fail with an un-throttled client program, like so:

```py
import random
import socket
import secrets

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('localhost', 1234))

count = 0

try:
    while True:
        count += 1
        sock.send(secrets.token_bytes(random.randint(8, 65)))
        sock.recv(10)
        print(".", end="")
        # time.sleep(0.01)
except Exception as e:
    print()
    print(f'Exception: {e}')
    print(f'count: {count}')
```

This is going to result in:

```
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I understand what is happening here, no question around that. Though, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) of the `send` function of the sockets module doesn't mention that this exception might be raised.

Most functions in the sockets module might fail for various reasons, it's easy to miss catching possible exceptions and deal with them gracefully.

What documentation should be consulted to understand which exceptions might be raised by functions in the sockets module?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#exceptions

Comment: i am aware of that listing, but it's not really helpful. It doesn't mention at all which concrete exceptions can occur in which situations, hence you can't write code that takes those situations into account. How would I know to catch BlockingIOError for a send() call and try resending?

Comment: I think the problem is that the methods propagate exceptions of the system calls etc. (OSError). The implementation itself can therefore not know what errors it can expect from the system and a large number of exceptions can occur (depending on os). In any case you can catch OSError. From the "errorno" you can see the reason. BlockingIOError is subclass of socket.error/OSError. Look into OSError documentation an search for socket: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError

Comment: True, the exceptions might be platform-specific. Still, this is a suboptimal situation. Reacting to OSError in general is not specific enough in practice. Assuming Linux, you want to treat BlockingIOError differently than other exceptions. You practically have to wait for a fault and implement exception handling based on that. If you put code into a critial environment, it's easy to see that this is undesirable. It would be good to get more clarity about possible exceptions on every platform.

Comment: I understand your issue. You can use the errorno of the OSError object to find out the exact reason. Also you can find out under "OS exceptions" which OS-errorno are mapped to which OS exception objects (https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSexceptions). You can also find a list of all possible errornos and their mapping to specific exception objects (https://docs.python.org/3/library/errno.html).

Comment: Also you have to look which of them are used by sockets (Socket Error Codes by OS). These are then also all possible exceptions that can occur. So I think for your case BlockingIOError and BrokenPipeError/ConnectionError are important (or are interesting to differentiate them).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything with that. There are a lot of errors that can occur during socket operation, so you should probably catch *OSError* (parent of all socket errors) and handle the exceptions that you want using the exception's `errno` parameter.

Comment: The question is, how do I understand which errnos can occur.

Comment: Each operating system has its own set of errors; you should read the Python source code to learn which os errors Python recognizes for socket operations.